# How can I dynamically add multiple rows to a table is ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

Here's what I had so far, code-wise:

```
Protected Sub btnAddRow7_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddRow7.Click

    Dim tableRow As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow
    Dim tableCell As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
    Dim textBox As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

    tableCell.Controls.Add(textBox)

    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell)

    tbl7.Rows.Add(tableRow)

End Sub
```

...but it only adds one row dynamically. After the first addition, more clicks to the button will not add more rows. Any idea why? Better way to do this?

Comment: What is tbl7 and does it have ViewState enabled?

Comment: Sorry - tbl7 is the table declared in the ASP code - this is the VB code behind. Yes, ViewState is enabled.

Comment: Anything in your Page_Load event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rebuild your Table in Page.Load. For example:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    rebuildMyTable()
End Sub

Private Sub rebuildMyTable()
    If Me.ViewState("TableRowCount") Is Nothing Then Me.ViewState("TableRowCount") = 0
    For i As Int32 = 0 To CInt(Me.ViewState("TableRowCount")) - 1
        AddTableRow()
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub AddTableRow()
    Dim tableRow As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow
    Dim tableCell As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
    Dim textBox As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

    tableCell.Controls.Add(textBox)

    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell)

    Me.MyTable.Rows.Add(tableRow)
End Sub

Protected Sub BtnAddRow_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAddRow.Click
    AddTableRow()

    If Me.ViewState("TableRowCount") Is Nothing Then
        Me.ViewState("TableRowCount") = 1
    Else
        Me.ViewState("TableRowCount") = CInt(Me.ViewState("TableRowCount")) + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

This is because the Button Event comes after the Viewstate is registered.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: I think this is probably the best solution...although this is going to balloon into something pretty complex. This one page is going to have 14 or so tables. Anyway, thank you for the help - this is what I needed to get started!

Answer (score 0):

HtmlTable doesn't appear to have any kind of ViewState awareness, so either build all of your rows on every postback or use an asp:Table or an asp:Repeater instead.